# add inputs dynamically react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, dynamicform

hello I will ask this question again because I still can’t find a answer
I try to create a form similar to google form with react and redux

each question is represented by: QuestionCard
contains a title and can have several types (short question, long question, choice ,multiple, single choice ...)
I manage to add cardQuestion and delete them

[image]
my problem is that when I select single choice I want to give the user the possibility to add the number of choices he wants but it does not work

this is my reducer

```js
const initialState = {
    formId: '',
    form: {
        
        title: '',
        description: ''
    },
    basicForm: {
        fullName: '',
        age: '',
       
        saved: false
    },
    cardQuestion: [{
        
        title: '',
        choix: [],
        type: '',
        

    }],
    error: "",
    loading: false,
}

const addRequestReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_STATE':
            return { ...state, ...action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

i use a global state

and this how i try to add choices

1- i handle change of inputs (each choice) like this :

```js
  const { cardQuestion } = useSelector((state) => state.addRequest)
const choice = cardQuestion.map(e => e.choix)

   const onChangeInput = (i, key, value) => {
        console.log(value)
        dispatch({
            type: 'SET_STATE',
            payload: {
                cardQuestion: cardQuestion.map((elem, index) => {
                    console.log(i)
                    console.log(i === index)
                    if (i !== index) return elem
                    return { ...elem, [`${key}`]: value }
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

2- use the ChangeInptut like this

```js
<div >{choice.map((elem, i) => <div key={i}>
                            <Input value={elem.choix} onChange={(e) => onChangeInput(i, 'choix', e.target.value)} />
   </div>
```

3- button to add new input (choice)

```js
<Button onClick={() => dispatch({
                                type: 'SET_STATE',
                                payload: {
                                    cardQuestion: [...cardQuestion, { choix: '' }]


                                }
                            })} >Add</Button>

                        </div>
```

but it give me results like this :
[image]

and when i add a choice in question card1  it is also added in questioncard2

how can i resolve this , any help will be appreciated

Comment: why are you not dispatching different types of actions? maybe a good starting point would be to think about what state changes you actually want to happen.

Comment: what do you suggest to change choice?

Comment: How do you know which card you're currently on?

Comment: i add an index to each cardQuestion: if (i !== index) return elem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
cardQuestion: [...cardQuestion, { choix: '' }]
```

adds a new card without a title or type to the list of cards. If I understand you correctly, you want to add a new choice to an existing card, which will look something like

```
const newCards = [...cardQuestion]
newCards[currentCardPosition] = {...newCards[currentCardPosition]}
newCards[currentCardPosition].choix = [...newCards[currentCardPosition].choix, '' ]
```

but I don't see where `currentCardPosition` will come from

Comment: Hello what currentCardPosition represent ?

Comment: `currentCardPosition` is the index of the card where you want to add a new choice

Comment: thank you for your answer but i dont know how to use it

Comment: I think the problem is you have 2 arrays: cards and choices,but only one index between them. Can you create a sandbox on codepen or similar with your code, so we see how we can add the second index?

Comment: thank you for your response here is the sandbox but i didn't add the backend, you can find the code above on the file QuestionCard https://df5kp.csb.app/

Comment: Your current implementation takes all choices from all cards and renders them together. Is that really what you want to achieve? if so, why do you need to store choices under cards at all? I recommend you to add a few dummy cards with a few choices each into your initial data and see how it renders, will it look like you expect?

Comment: i want to get result like this for each card: title:'exemple', type:'example', choice:[0:example1, 2: example2....] should i add another index?

Comment: Your component already receives some sort of cardId, if I remember rightly, but I don't see any id on the cards. In any case, the component should get the state for one card only and update only that card using either id or index of the card. Currently you're using the index of the choice to identify the card. Think of them as numbers of buildings and numbers of flats inside, if you need to find a flat you need both numbers.

Comment: i add an index for cards in the parent of Question card component (RequestBuider) so when i change a title of one card it change for only one card and same for type, the issue is only in choice i  dont know how to fix it

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot explain it better. Try talking to someone in person.

Comment: okay thank you, can you resolve it on sandbox ?

Comment: If you can create sandbox where the user will be able to navigate between two cards coming from the initial state (each with a few choices), independently edit their title and see only choices related to the card, I can show you how to add a new choice.

Comment: my problème is here, i can add a new choice but it also add in the second card, i can change the title and the type of each card separatly except choice

Comment: If that is the case then you should have no problem producing a sandbox with two cards.

Comment: yes please you can see it on sandbox https://bdpr2.csb.app

Comment: yes please you can see it on sandbox https://bdpr2.csb.app

Comment: have a look, hope it'll make sense https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-voice-feovz?file=/src/Components/QuestionsCard/index.js

Comment: Thank you a lot you, you have solved a problem that has blocked me for days I am grateful to you. thank'sss